# Writing multiple files a loop in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Hi I'm using a for each loop to in nodejs script to write multiple files to a local location.For the courseTitleArray I'm using "Biology 101,ruby" and I can write one file **successfully** but **not the both**.Please help me out.

Here is my code so far

```
  for (var value in CourseTitleArray) {
               console.log( "Course Title " + CourseTitleArray[value]);
               var newImageLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'app/img/courseImages', CourseTitleArray[value] +  ".png");

                  fs.readFile(image.path, function(err, data) {
                      fs.writeFile(newImageLocation, data, function(err) {
                      console.log(CourseTitleArray[value] + " was  created successfully");   




                      });
                  }); 

                console.log("Loop executed " +  value);  
             }
```

And in the console I get following logs.

```
Course Title Biology 101
Loop executed 0
Course Title ruby
Loop executed 1
ruby was  created successfully
ruby was  created successfully
```

It seems the loops working fine and as in the log I can see both titles.
But when it's writing "Biology 101,ruby" have executed twice .

Can anybody help me out with this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that your callback is called when the loop is finished, so `value` has changed.

A solution is to use a closure to store the value of `value` :

```
for (var value in CourseTitleArray) {
     (function(value){
               console.log( "Course Title " + CourseTitleArray[value]);
               var newImageLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'app/img/courseImages', CourseTitleArray[value] +  ".png");

                  fs.readFile(image.path, function(err, data) {
                      fs.writeFile(newImageLocation, data, function(err) {
                      console.log(CourseTitleArray[value] + " was  created successfully");   

                      });
                  }); 
                console.log("Loop executed " +  value);  
      })(value);
}
```

Note that it's not clear what you mean with your "Loop executed" log : when you log, the writing hasn't yet occurred.

Comment: @AmilaIddamalgoda Yes, fixed it. But it would have been easier if you had correctly indented your code to start with.

Comment: Yes mate!! my bad I fixed it already and this is working fine..Thnk you very much for pointing out the cause and giving me the solution..really appreciate it :)